# Can't return class instance parameters after getting class instance

Tags: python, class, instance

I'm having trouble calling back a class' self.name.

I'm a bit lost because i pulled this from another file i'm working on where calling "classinstance[0].parameter" works but it won't here.
Basically i can get the class instance from BidRequest.find_bid_request(), but i can't return any of the parameters of the BidRequest class that i have pulled.

```
#__main__.py
from BidRequest import BidRequest
from NewEntryForm import NewEntryForm
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    # NewEntryForm()

    BidRequest.load_bids()



    found_bid = BidRequest.find_bid_request('My Job')
    ###here is where i'm having the problem###
    print(found_bid[0].name)
```

````
#BidRequest.Py
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk



class BidRequest:
  instances = []
  def __init__(self,name,due_date,city,state,contractor,designation,platform,plans_link,contact_name,contact_email,contact_num,*estimates):
    self.name = name
    self.due_date = due_date
    self.city = city
    self.state = state
    self.contractor = contractor
    self.designation = designation
    self.platform = platform
    self.plans_link = plans_link
    self.contact_name = contact_name
    self.contact_email = contact_email
    self.contact_num = contact_num
    self.estimates = estimates
    BidRequest.instances.append(self)

  @classmethod
  def find_bid_request(self, search_name):
      try:
        return [inst for inst in self.instances if inst.name == search_name]
      except AttributeError:
        tk.messagebox.showinfo(title=None, message=f'No job by the name {search_name} was found.')
        


  @staticmethod
  def load_bids(self):
    
        bid_df = pd.read_csv('bid_request.csv',) 

        for index, row in bid_df.iterrows():
          BidRequest(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9],row[10])```
````

Comment: `load_bids` is creating and immediately discarding multiple instances of `BidRequest`. As a class method, it should *return* an instance (or a list of instances, as it appears you want it to return).

Comment: i had staticmethod and classmethod reversed, but it appears to be creating the classes fine. I don't use a return in the other program where it works either
```    
@classmethod
    def load_pokemon(self):
        import pandas as pd
        poke_df = pd.read_csv('pokemon_list_final.csv',) 

        for index, row in poke_df.iterrows():
            Pokemon(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9])
```

Comment: Having `__init__` used only for the side effect of appending the new instance to a list is pretty unorthodox. It should just initialize `self`, and whoever *calls* `BidRequest` should be responsible for adding the object to a list.

Comment: @chepner: I don't think your assessment is entirely correct. I've seen and used this pattern to both construct an object and keep track of all constructed objects. This is especially useful if you create instances of `BidRequest` from multiple places and don't want to have each of those places remember to add the bid to a list.

Comment: This code seems to work fine for me when I use ordinary data rather than whatever "pd" is. Can you please create a complete minimal reproducible example, and preferably one that doesn't rely on an external data file? It would also help if you reduced the number of elements in the class to just a couple for the purposes of this question. Have you verified that search_name is what you assume it is inside of find_bid_request? Have you examined the items in BidRequest.instances to see if it contains what you assume it contains?

Comment: In your code, what does `print(found_bid[0].name)` do? Does it print the wrong information? Does it throw an error? If so, what error? Have you verified that `found_bid` has what you expect, and that `found_bid[0]` is actually an instance of `BidRequest`?

Comment: the error was found. The dataframe was a csv file that needed to be reformated because it had two hidden rows of data that couldn't be read by the layman and needed to be fixed.
TLDR: Dataframe error

Comment: @BryanOakley You have a reference to `BidRequest` available in all your various places; you can just as easily provide a reference to the list to the same places without tying the list to the class.

Comment: @chepner: yes, you can. I think you missed the point. If you have to remember to add it to the list everywhere you create one, there's a chance you'll forget to do that when you are developing for refactoring the code. Having a single point where items are added to a list avoids that problem.

Answer (score 0):

the error was found. The dataframe was a csv file that needed to be reformated because it had two hidden rows of data that couldn't be read by the layman and needed to be fixed.
TLDR: Dataframe error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).